# Strange behavior of Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, assumptions

I'm trying to calculate the following integral using *Mathematica 9.0.1.0*

```
 a11=Integrate[Abs[Sin[b+x]],{x,0,2*\[Pi]}]
```

This should be a simple problem; however, it took *Mathematica* a very long time to obtain the answer, which is **4**. I asked a colleague to do it with *Maple*, the answer is obtained instantly. I thought may be this has something to do with the fact that *Mathematica* treats everthing as Complex value, so I rewrote the programm as

```
a1=Integrate[Abs[Sin[b+x]],{x,0,2*\[Pi]},Assumptions->{Element[{b,x},Reals]}]
```

Unfortunately, it took *Mathematica* even more time to run this command. What's more unfortunate is that the obtained answer is **wrong**:

```
4 Abs[Sin[b]] Cot[b]
```

Does anybody know what's wrong here?

Comment: It's even more unfortunate that `Integrate[Abs[Sin[b + x]], {x, 0, 2  Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> {b \[Element] Reals}]` returns `0` for me.

Comment: @b.gatessucks. I tried your way, it returns 0, too. Is this a BUG?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: It does seem to be one. I've tagged appropriately. (For fun, see what happens if you use assumptions like `b > 0` or `b < 0`, or some finite interval.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FullSimplify@ Integrate[Abs@Sin[b + x] , {x, 0, 2 Pi},   Assumptions -> {0 < b < 2 Pi}]

(*
 4
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In[77]:= $Version

Out[77]= "9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 25, 2013)"

In[73]:= Timing[All = Integrate[Abs[Sin[b + x]], {x, 0, 2*\[Pi]}]]


Out[73]= {81.073720, 4}

In[75]:= Timing[
 FullSimplify@
  Integrate[Abs@Sin[b + x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Assumptions -> {0 < b < 2 Pi}]]

(*4*)


Out[75]= {1.404009, 4}
```